# histamine inter-cellular and cytoplasmic binding site

Tags: proteins, protein-evolution, cell-signaling

I noticed that HRH (histamine receptor) has an inter-cellular and cytoplasmic binding site of anti-histamines which are equal in binding energy. Does anyone know what is the function of the well formed cytoplasmic ligand binding site?

Comment: What is HRH ? Tried googling...didn't get anything.

Comment: HRH is histamine receptor